# A script calling ifconfig up and openvpn service won't work, but if the interface is already up it works

Tags: shell-script, openvpn

I'm facing a weird problem, I have a script like this one :

```
ifconfig eth0 up
sleep 2
systemctl start openvpn@client.service
```

If `eth0` is down prior to calling this script then openvpn will fail to connect. `journalctl` returns

> openvpn Control process exited code exited status=1, Failed to start OpenVPN connection to client

However if I rerun this same script a second time with `eth0` being up from the first call, it works just fine.. Any idea what is happening and how to fix this ?

Comment: Could you add a line like `ifconfig -a > /tmp/script.log` (or preferably `ip addr show > /tmp/script.log`) just after `sleep 2`?  It will allow to find if the interface if actually coming up in 2 seconds.  If that is the problem it can be easily fixed by making a systemd dependency chain.

Comment: @grochmal it goes up but doesn't seem to acquire a link and inet ip. After the script ends with the systemctl error message the IP gets acquired on that interface.

Comment: @Yeah waiting 10 sec for it to acquire an ip works. Btw how would you do a systemd chain ? How to do a chain based on the interface having an inet ?

Comment: Next question, is there a reason why you start the interface manually?  e.g. you plug a cable and then start the VPN? (it might be easier to force an interface up whenever a cable is connected.) Also what is your distro (different distros use different things for network services)?

Comment: @grochmal I'm starting manually because I have a script to shutdown internet (ifconfig down, openvpn off) just want this to get to work. I'm under arch. I'm going to write a loop to stall until inet gets up but I'm interested in how to get this done via systemd

Answer (score 2):

Arch is great for that kind of configuration.  Yet, you should really not be using `ifconfig` on Arch, it had switched to `iproute2` a long time ago, and it is considerably better to do:

```
ip link set dev eth0 up
dhcpcd eth0
```

("Better" because you have two steps and you know exactly which step fails.  Also, I believe you do not have `eth0` but something like `enp1s0` but that's a minor detail.)

---

Anyhow, instead of `ifconfig eth0` you can start a wired interface with:

```
systemctl start netctl-auto@eth0.service
```

And then you can simply change the openvpn service, first copy the service file:

```
cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service /etc/systemd/system/openvpn@.service
```

And then change it (the copy) to:

```
[Unit]
...
Requires=netctl-auto@eth0.service
After=netctl-auto@eth0.service
```

(That is not too much of a hack, even [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN#Resolve_issues) suggests this.  There is a dispute over that article because it uses the `/usr/lib/systemd` file, so I adapted the answer to make it the proper way by copying it first)

---

Now you should be able to start the VPN with

```
systemctl start openvpn@client.service
```

and the network will be started first.  And stop both with:

```
systemctl stop netctl-auto@eth0.service
```